# When background image scaled, it starts to flicker in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have a div with a background image on it. When it has simple transform scale animation, it starts to flicker in Google Chrome and Opera. 
Here is a simple exmple:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWpNYq

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url(".....jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Script:

```
TweenLite.set('div', {
  backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
  perspective: 1000
});
TweenLite.fromTo('div', 10, {
  scale: 1.1
}, {
  scale: 1
});
```

When the image is a simple img element, the same scale animation works fine. The transition is smooth:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPyvdp

The examples use GASP for animations. I need a solution which use GSAP to scale the div with better result.

Do you any idea how to make it smooth with background image?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**
Add `transition: all 1s linear;` so it scale smoothly.

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url("https://smartslider3.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/slide52.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: I want to stick with GSAP animation engine.

Comment: This does in fact work in combination with GSAP. The `1s` is overkill, but adding `transition: transform 0.1s linear;` in your first demo makes it smooth for me. The underlying issue is probably that the `background-size: cover` makes it so that the image is scaled slightly differently depending on the scaled size of the `div`. Adding the transition smooths this away.

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe you can try out this css animation. For better browser support add

```
-webkit-animation
-moz-animation
-o-animation
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url("https://smartslider3.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/slide52.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation:  animate 5s forwards; 
animation: animate 5s forwards; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0%   { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(1.1); }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%   { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(1.1); }
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 allows you to add native transition to your transformations. Try to use code below:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var div = document.getElementById('img');
  div.style.transform = 'scale(.5)';
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url("https://smartslider3.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/slide52.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  transition: transform 30s;    
}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
```

It uses css property "transition" and starts transition on body click.

Comment: But GSAP works with the same image when it is an img tag, I do not see why would it harder to animate background image.

Answer (score 0):

Just use css, way better. If you open up your inspector you'll see that your tweenlite code is setting/ updating the style attribute of your div very fast with this piece of code: `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1.00212, 1.00212);`.
This is JS calculating something and then telling CSS what to do (very basic explanation). CSS can do this on it's own. Why do you want to stick with your GSAP engine so badly?